# Bug when editing question: "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0."

Tags: bug, editing, mobile-web

Sometimes, after editing a *question*, I get the

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0.

This has only occured on the mobile site and the app for me so far, but I suppose that's only because I use those most often.

Comment: Lesson for life: don't use the mobile app, don't use the mobile site.

Comment: How reproducible is this for you?  I get the impression from your phrasing it happens "sometimes", not always.

Comment: @hardmath Not very reproducible: I don't know what causes it. Yes, it only happens sometimes.

Comment: I had this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2847140/104041).